# Is it actually possible to remove "Pi" from Calculus of Constructions?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, lambda-calculus

The article [Simpler, Easier!](http://augustss.blogspot.com.br/2007/10/simpler-easier-in-recent-paper-simply.html) claims it could be possible to encode dependent type systems even without the presence of "Pi" - that is, you could reuse the "Lam" constructor for it. But how can that be true, if "Pi" and "Lam" are treated differently in some cases?

Moreover, could "Star" be removed? I think you could replace all occurrences of it by "λ x . x" (id).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just overloading like `(a, b)` in Haskell: it can be both a type and a value. You can use the same binder for `Π` and `λ` and typechecker will decide from the context which one you mean. If you typecheck one binder against another, then the former is `λ` and the latter is `Π` — and that's why you can't unambiguously replace `*` with `λ x . x` — because then the former binder could be `Π` and the latter is `*` (`*` as a binder doesn't make any sense to me). There is a bigger problem with `∀ = λ` and `* = λ x . x`: by transitivity `* = ∀ x . x`, which is a common way to postulate `False` — this type must be uninhabited in a sound system, so you won't have any types at all.

There was a recent thread on Coq-club "Similarities between forall and fun" (gmane.org gives me "No such message", is it just me?), here are some excerpts:

**Dominic Mulligan**:

> And here is another with a small bibliography pointing to similar work:
>
> http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~fairouz/forest/papers/journals-publications/jfp05.pdf
>
> Ironically, according to that paper Coquand first presented the Calculus of
>   Constructions with a single, unified binder, following a convention
>   established by De Bruijn in AutoMath.

**Thorsten Altenkirch:**

> A function and its type are very different concepts even if they have
>   some superficial syntactic similarity.
>
> Especially for the newcomer this identification is very confusing and
>   completely misleading. I do think that one should understand type
>   theoretical concepts from what they mean and not how they look like.

**Andreas Abel**:

> My student Matthias Benkard also worked on such a system, see "Type
>   Checking without Types"
>
> http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/benkardThesis.pdf

Note that the system described at the first link has Π-reduction (i.e. you can apply pi-types just like lambdas) — your system will have it too, if you unify `Π` and `λ` internally (as opposed to syntactically). And the system described at the second link unifies types and values

> One immediate consequence is the absence of any distinction between
>   types and their inhabitants: Every value is a type containing itself
>   and all of its parts; and conversely, every type is a composite value
>   consisting of its inhabitants.

so there is really just one binder (except for `let` and maybe `fix`).

Comment: Sorry I do not understand how you're able to know when it should be a Pi and when it should be a λ by context. Could you elaborate a little bit on the distinction?

Comment: As a simple example, `λ (a : *) -> λ (x : a) -> a` applied to itself. What would happen? Since `a : *` and everything is a type, wouldn't this term accept everything?

Comment: @Viclib, I have a little typechecker for a basic dependent type theory, I'll try to merge `Π` and `λ`. If you have `[a : *] -> [x : a] -> a` and you apply it to itself, then the first binder acts like a lambda and the result is `[x : [a : *] -> [x : a] -> a] -> a`.

Comment: But that's my issue. How do you know the first binder should act like a lambda? To me it seems that doing that will allow you to express anything, for example, `(λ (x : *) -> (x x)) (λ (x : *) -> (x x))` reduces to itself because the first binder is treated as a λ, and that goes on forever. How are you able to say it is OK to apply `(λ (a : *) -> λ (x : a) -> a)` to itself, but not `(λ (x : *) -> (x x))`?

Comment: @Viclib, `λ (x : *) -> (x x)` is not typeable and we don't reduce untyped expressions. One problem is that in the same `t = [ x : * ] -> ...` a binder can be treated in one place as a lambda and in another as a pi and all in the same expression. I'm not sure how bad it is, but it can be prevented by remembering which binder what denote.

Comment: @Viclib, I wrote a bit of code and here are some problems I encountered: in `([ x : _ ] [ y : _ ] -> x) x y` both binders are lambdas, but to show this we must either reduce terms as soon as possible (not sure whether it is safe, but probably yes) or keep track of to how many arguments a function is applied. When we infer the type of `f x` (since we have explicit types everywhere, all terms are inferrable), we know that `f` is a function, but don't know what `x` is. If `f` is a lambda and `x` contains binders, then we must reduce the expression.

Comment: We can't leave uninstantiated binders in a fully typed term. What's the type of `[x : _] -> ...`? It can be both `Π _ _` and `*`. Dealing with all these details looks too tedious. In any case it's better to use `Π` and `λ` explicitly.

Comment: I still don't understand the origin of the asymmetry between Pi and Lam. Would it be possible to have a simpler, more symmetrical  system, with the practical utilities (type checking, proving correctness, totality, etc) of CoC? I'll make a new question for that one.

Comment: @Viclib, "Would it be possible to have a simpler, more symmetrical system" — I'm sure it's not. It's like asking "would it be possible to have a simpler, more symmetrical system, if we replace every 'd' and 'b' with 'o|o' and decide from a context whether 'o|o' is 'b' or 'd'?" It obscures your code, it complicates your typechecker. I can't say better than Thorsten Altenkirch (a quote is in my answer).

Comment: Hmm I see. So, what I might need is understanding how this remarkably specific system, with 2 very similar yet different constructs, is so interesting and powerful. Maybe time experience will tell me so. Thanks for all your answers (:

Comment: Btw do you have a link to the archive of that thread? How did you get those quotes?

Comment: @Viclib, what one might do is to express both `Π` and `λ` in terms of the same `bind` like this: `Π = bind pi`, `λ = bind lam`. That's how it is in the [Typed Syntactic Meta-programming](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/404549/1/icfp002-devriese-authorversion.pdf) paper. Thanks for all your questions, I learned a lot while studying answers to them or writing my own.

Comment: I don't have a link (thy [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.logic.coq.club/16292), but it doesn't work for me; if it doesn't work for you too, try to google "Similarities between forall and fun" and read cached messages), I get the quotes from incoming messages in my gmail.